# How to set color of cell with JExcel API

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I want to know how to set color to cells in Excel using JExcel API. A sample program would do as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Before asking questions google your issues first of all, then ask it here;
i think you're looking for [jxl.format.color](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/format/Colour.html)

You may also look into the following thread [Making new colors in JExcelApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834973/making-new-colors-in-jexcelapi)

you'll have to use [jxl.write.label](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/jxl/write/Label.html) to include color to your cell

```
Label label_name = new Label(col_num, row_num, "value", getCellFormat(Colour.GREEN, Pattern.GRAY_25));
```

Comment: how can i change the color of an already existing cell?